# pycodestyle "continuation line unaligned" not obviously correct - bug, configurable or user error?

Tags: python, pep8, pycodestyle

This is a minimal example based on my code:

```
def fn(self):
    Foo() \
        .with_bar(
            Bar()
                .with_baz('Baz')
        )
```

I find this quite readable, but `pycodestyle` complains:

> stdin:5:17: E131 continuation line unaligned for hanging indent

In almost every case `pycodestyle` reports issues which, when fixed, improve the readability of the code. However, this time the following code seems to be the only accepted solution:

```
def fn(self):
    Foo() \
        .with_bar(
            Bar()
            .with_baz('Baz')
        )
```

This seems much less readable: the indentation is *inconsistent* with the default continuation indentation used for `Foo`, and it makes `.with_baz('Baz')` look like a *parameter* to `with_bar`. Is this something I should simply get used to, is it a bug in `pycodestyle`, or is there an alternative formatting which conserves the general style of breaking up subsequent `with_*` calls that is PEP 8 compatible?

(Please imagine there are more `with` methods on both `Foo` and `Bar` - the whole thing is a builder pattern which needs to be split into multiple lines to be PEP 8 compatible and pleasant to read. I **cannot** simply join the lines to fix the issue. Pulling out the `Bar` as a variable is of course an option, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: I can only agree. I have a similar case where aligning all to the left makes it much less readable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer relevant for me.